# How to update the data by comparing values of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1. `shoemaster`
2. `DataFix`

In the `DataFix` table, I need to update size number by comparing two tables size and genderid.

`shoemaster`:

```
productsizeid   size    genderId
---------------------------------
114             6        800
115             6.5      800
103             6        801
104             6.5      801
```

`DataFix` table:

```
size   genderId   sizeno
-------------------------
6      800         Null
6.5    800         Null
6      801         Null
```

I need to write update query for `DataFix` table `sizeno` from `shoemaster` based on `genderid` and `size` values comparing to update the second (`DataFix`) table.

`sizeno` should update like below output of DataFix table:

output-DataFix  Table

```
size   genderId   sizeno
6      800         114
6.5    800         115
6      801         104
```

Please help me to write update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE T SET
  T.sizeno=X.sizeno
FROM DataFix AS T
JOIN shoemaster AS X ON T.SIZE=X.SIZE AND T.genderId=X.genderId
```